# Add columns from one data frame to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Data Frames with data that I want to put side by side in a new data frame:

```
DF1:
   A        B
0  Apple    Fruit
1  Banana   Fruit

DF2:
   C   D
0  X   2
1  Y   1
```

Expected Output:

```
DF3:
   A        B      C   D
0  Apple    Fruit  X   2
1  Banana   Fruit  Y   1
```

I have tried:
`DF3 = pd.concat([DF1,DF2],axis=1,ignore_index=True)`
however this has not worked.
It outputs the following:

```
DF3:
   A        B      C     D
0  Apple    Fruit  NaN   NaN
1  Banana   Fruit  NaN   NaN
3  Nan      NaN    X     2
4  Nan      NaN    Y     1
```

Aside: The values are not an exact match for example I believe the Indexes are 19, 20, 321, 322 as DF1 and DF2 originated from different Dataframes

Any help appreciated

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` works for me

Comment: As I said I have tried that but it doesn't work, thanks though

Comment: Could you describe why it doesn't work, for instance by showing the output you receive?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Similar to the edit the data is not an exact replica slightly different figures

Comment: It seems that your `df2` has different index values `[3, 4]` compared to `df1`, which has index `[0, 1]`. You're dealing with an index misalignment. You could for instance solve it by resetting and dropping the current index for df2 (and maybe for df1 too)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Not quite sure what you mean

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. At the top you said DF2 has index `[0, 1]`, but in your output, the DF2 rows have index `[3, 4]`. You should clean up the example details, otherwise it's very confusing to understand/answer the true problem.

Comment: If both df1 and df2 have nonstandard indices (i.e. not 0, 1, 2, 3...), then when you use `pd.concat` only rows with the same index in both df1 and df2 will appear on the same row in the output. If you don't care about the indices, then you can use: `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)` which will reset both dataframes to a standard 0, 1, 2, ... index

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs What if you care about 1 of the indices, or is there a way to set them? For example in a loop can you set one of the indices to be i if looping through the other dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

if you want one next to another, just reset de index and then concat.

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Comment: The values are not an exact match for example I believe the Indexes are 19, 20, 321, 322 as DF1 and DF2 originated from different Dataframes

Edit:
Reset index of which?

Comment: Just reset the index

Comment: That throws this error: ValueError: All objects passed were None
When trying to Concat Edit: Using `Df.reset_index(drop=True)` worked

Comment: What if you care about 1 of the indices, or is there a way to set them? For example in a loop can you set one of the indices to be i if looping through the other dataframe

Comment: What on of the indices? give me an example pls